# Is OWIN a replacement for Dependency Injection as they share common features, or do they work together?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, owin

I've been following [This MSDN tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/12/per-request-lifetime-management-for-usermanager-class-in-asp-net-identity.aspx) about implementing OWIN to manage a single instance of DbContext and Identity UserManager classes.

It seems nice, but I'm also learning about Dependency Injection (I've been using Ninject) to get instances of objects.

I understand that OWIN creates and retrieves a single instance of an object per request and DI will return a new instance for every time that we require an object.

**Do the two work together or share common features?**

**Should I be choosing one or the other or both together?**

For example, should I be setting up an interface that has methods to return instances of my objects from the OWIN context and then injecting that into my controller?

Answer (score 3):

The `CreatePerOwinContext/Context.Get` approach is *not* a general replacement for a regular IoC container and does not contain the [expected] features associated with dependency management - trivially, it *provides no method for injecting dependencies*. If anything, it is more akin to a basic [Service Locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) or [ab]use of the HttpContext.

Thus, while it can be used to *establish* an IoC container, it does *not* replace DI or an IoC container.

Comment: Would I be correct to set up an interface and an implementation with methods that return my OWIN instances and then using DI to inject them in where required?  It seems a bit bizarre to specify a property on all of my controllers to return the instances as shown in the examples I've seen.  Id love to know your thoughts.

Comment: @Coulton I do *not* recommend using that, even to start the injection root (because well, it's not a singular root). There are better DI-root entry points. See [these instructions on using Ninject with OWIN](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/Setting-up-a-OWIN-WebApi-application), where the magic/DI comes in at creation of the controllers themselves. In cases where this is not practical (as I've had to deal with in WebForms), then use a base type to help establish the DI-root and initial injections.